# How to insert Excel file values into multiple tables in SQL

Tags: java, sql, import-from-excel

1. The Excel file data could be inserted into two or more tables.
2. The mapping between the table in which the data needs to be inserted, its column, and the Excel column header is configurable.
3. Every time the Excel file is supplied as input to your application, it dynamically fetches the data matching the correct column header and inserts that data into its respective tables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you be able to describe some of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Why do not you try different sheets. As far as I know `Apache POI` can read/write Excel, It can distinguish sheets but two tables in a sheet? I recommend to try 2 sheets and POI